# How to set up a cron

Tags: php, mysql, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

I have this PHP script which updates my database when the webpage is visited via https://......

```
    <?php
//
database connection file.....


        if($wa->cron()){

        echo "Updated";
    }
     ?>
```

How can I set a cronjob to visit this every 24hours?

I entered these commands but didn't work /home/xxxxx/public_html/cron.php and /home/xxx/public_html/cron.php

and I entered the web address directly still didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to setup a cronjob in linux to call your php file every 24 hours here's how you do it.
In your terminal type `contab -e`, select your preferred editor and at the end of the file type:

```sh
0 0 * * * php /path/to/your/script.php
```

This will call that script every day at midnight (your server's time). Also be careful, as crontab runs under your currently logged user and running these commands as `root` might expose your server to some dangers.